# Purpose of Causal Discovery if I can include all variables in a Causal Forest Model for Causal Inference

Tags: machine-learning, inference, random-forest, causality

It appears to me that I can include all variables in the dataset into a causal forest (whether or not they are confounders), as the model would conduct feature selection to identify important variables to determine the treatment effect.

Is the above statement true? If yes, then what would be the point of conducting Causal Discovery to identify causal relationships between variables if I could just throw all the variables in a Causal Forest model to get the treatment effect?

Let me know if you need further clarifications, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with causal forests, but from what I understand they are a treatment effect estimation method. So if my true model is $X \to Y$, and I ask the causal forest to estimate $Y \to X$, I may get some result, but there is no way it can be causal. Similarly, one has to be careful to include all confounders (but not colliders) as covariates. All of this requires knowledge of the causal structure, which is where causal discovery comes in.

In short: without having first discovered which is a cause and which an effect, how is one to even use a causal forest?